# Angular Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

After taking a break from Angular, I've decided to jump back onto the bandwagon. I'm currently working on a relatively small project to help me get used to the framework in full, and I've found myself stuck.

I've read over and over that using jQuery with AngularJS is forbidden taboo, though I can't necessarily comprehend how to do the following purely in AngularJS,

### controller.js

```
(function(){

    angular.module('app')
        .controller('homeCtrl', ['cache', 'page', '$scope', function(cache, page, $scope) {
            page.title.set('Home');
            if( !cache.getKey('welcomed') ) {
                $( "#welcome-message" ).fadeTo( 3000 , 0, function() {
                    $( "#welcome-message" ).hide();
                    $( "#after-welcome" ).show();
                    $( "#after-welcome" ).fadeTo( 2500 , 100 );
                    // cache.setKey('welcomed', true);
                });
            } else {
                $( "#welcome-message" ).hide();
                $( "#after-welcome" ).show();
                $( "#after-welcome" ).fadeTo( 2500 , 100 );
            }
        }]);

})();
```

As can be seen, I simply want to fade out of a welcome message and into the main content. I know of ngAnimate, though I'm still a novice. My question standing is -- is there any simple way to accomplish what I've done above without the use of jQuery?

Comment: I suppose you could use CSS animations, but those are difficult to control properly with Javascript.  If it's just a simple page fade-in effect, CSS is your best bet.

Comment: It seems like you could use CSS and `ng-class` for something like this, but there are times when you may want to use a jQuery APi or something like that. In those cases, I believe you should do any DOM manipulation by using the `link: function() {}` and make sure to pass in the `scope, element, attrs` parameters if you want to do it the Angular Way with JQLite 

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/G0GwBh9j4u3tiJDjjYGO?p=catalogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery in AngularJS is not a forbidden taboo. Using jQuery to manipulate DOM in controllers is. You can use jQuery in directives or in animations. For example ([demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jfH2XOYNWQZH5gkPK0jy?p=preview)):

```
myModule.animation('.show-hide-animation', function() {
  return {
    beforeAddClass : function(element, className, done) {
      if(className == 'ng-hide') {
        element.fadeTo(2500, 0, function() {
          done();
        });
        return function() {
          element.css('opacity', null);
        }
      } else {
        done();
      }
    },

    removeClass : function(element, className, done) {
      if(className == 'ng-hide') {
          element.fadeTo( 3000 , 0, function() {
            element.fadeTo( 2500 , 1, function() {
              done();
            });
          });      
        return function() {
          element.css('opacity', null);
        }
      } else {
        done();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You can read more on javascript / jquery animations in:

- Angular official [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations).
- angular [ng-newsletter](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/25-days-of-angular/day-11) (I've used their demo as basis).